# Usage of か after verbs

Tags: grammar

In the following sentence

> 今日は何の映画を見るか決めたの

what is the grammatical role of か?

Comment: It makes an embedded question. I think you may need to be a bit more specific about what your problem is.

Comment: The question is why instead of こと, か is being used in the sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment it seems you are asking about the difference between:

> 1. 今日は何の映画を見るか決めた
>    Today I decided on which film I will watch.
> 2. 今日は何の映画を見ること(を)決めた
>    ????

In 1) 何の映画を見るか (which film will I watch) is an embedded question. The whole phrase behaves like a noun, which can take the optional object particle を. So the basic structure is

> 今日はXを決めた
> Today I decided on X

where X is "what film I will watch".

I don't believe sentence 2) is grammatical because of the question part 何の in it. You could say:

> 今日は映画を見ることを決めた
> I decided on watching a film

but that is a different structure with a different meaning.